# Non-orientable 3-manifold has infinite fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm doing past papers for a first course in algebraic topology.

The question is:

> Let $M$ be a 3-dimensional, closed, connected, non-orientable manifold. Show that $M$ has infinite fundamental group.

Is there any way of answering this question without simply quoting a classification theorem for 3-manifolds with finite fundamental group?

Comment: What definition are you using for orientability?

Comment: @dfeuer Good question. I guess I can assume that top homology vanishes.

Comment: @Earthliŋ, do you know a reference for such classification theorem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb Q}$If $\pi_1(M)$ is finite, $H_1(M;\QQ)=0$. If $M$ is non-orientable, $H_3(M;\QQ)=0$. So $\chi(M)=h_0(M;\QQ)-h_1(M;\QQ)+h_2(M;\QQ)-h_3(M;\QQ)=1+h_2(M;\QQ)>0$.

But by Poincaré duality, any odd-dimensional manifold has zero Euler characteristic.

Comment: A little remark: the Euler characteristic of any closed odd-dimensional manifold is 0, but in this case it doesn't follow by Poincaré duality, since $M$ is supposed to be non-orientable.

Comment: @Dario just use $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Sure! I didn't think to that. Thanks!

Comment: @Dario Or use the two-fold orientable cover $\tilde M\to M$. $\chi(\tilde M)=0$, and $\chi(\tilde M)=2\chi(M)$, hence $\chi(M)=0$.